# Typescript return union "either or" throws property not found error

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a Typescript helper function that returns a valid either/or type but I'm not understanding how to appease the compiler. My types are defined as follows:

```
export interface MediaElementUrl {
  media_type: 'image' | 'video';
  url: string;
  attachment_id: never;
  buttons?: Button[];
}

export interface MediaElementAttachmentId {
  media_type: 'image' | 'video';
  url: never;
  attachment_id: string;
  buttons?: Button[];
}

export type MediaElement = MediaElementUrl | MediaElementAttachmentId;
```

You can have a `MediaElement` that has a `url` **or** a `attachment_id` but not both. My helper class is as follows:

```
export class MediaElementComponent {
  protected constructor(
    public media_type: 'image' | 'video',
    public button: Button,
    public attachment_id?: string,
    public url?: string
  ) {}

  public validate(): void {
    if (this.attachment_id && this.url) throw new Error('Cannot set url and attachment_id');
  }

  public get(): MediaElement {
    if (this.attachment_id) {
      return {
        buttons: [this.button],
        media_type: this.media_type,
        attachment_id: this.attachment_id!,
      };
    }
    return {
      buttons: [this.button],
      media_type: this.media_type,
      url: this.url!,
    };
  }
}
```

The compiler is throwing an error on the return from `get()`

```
TS2322: Type '{ buttons: Button[]; media_type: "image" | "video"; attachment_id: string; }' is not assignable to type 'MediaElement'.   Property 'url' is missing in type '{ buttons: Button[]; media_type: "image" | "video"; attachment_id: string; }' but required in type 'MediaElementAttachmentId'.
```

Can anyone help me understand where I'm going wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple fix: You need to make the forbidden properties optional:

```
export interface MediaElementUrl {
  media_type: 'image' | 'video';
  url: string;
  attachment_id?: never;
  buttons?: Button[];
}

export interface MediaElementAttachmentId {
  media_type: 'image' | 'video';
  url?: never;
  attachment_id: string;
  buttons?: Button[];
}
```

Otherwise TypeScript will enforce that these properties are present with a type of `never`, which is impossible.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAQgVxCA9gOxgXhgbxgQwCMBjALhgGcQAnASzQHMYBfYYKADwhWpBnpBRqAM3zFYAWSgATWvgCiAGygBbKGhABVaotzAYMNbPwB9cNHIByWivwMolmAB8YlgG61pUFJYDc%20mAQdcio6Rn8DfGQxAAs1DRNPAH5yNCg3IQiYQiRUNAoU%20Fz0AG0AXX9Wdi4ePgEhUXEYKWMlVXUQAEFo4jiOgElpPQMjOTNIKCsbOwdnVw8vHyygxUK0jOosqJBY%20JBE6RCaegYsnOR0AvJEC7RyyrZObl4Yc0kZOTa9rGaPhWU9tpdC4Wp8AR1ujtentBv5qs8%20MRFPgKBRfq1wRoAMIoFTcNIaYYwCDUFCCYiCIbES40BAUngACgCBggCEIiloxEMf3GFlc03sjhc7k83ksABpmcS2Ryuec8tdimhJQYWTLOQQen0EskjmEGCrVaz2RqVoVQicAgBKXBVNUmrlufAc6RRKAMq3kNwoTxEgy0YQwBkgGK0CgAOm2uw6BxgADI469QxGVjaQ6SAO4wNJZ%20TUUnUBmWLH4NBoMmUKB8FYENBDKPQmOeSxWrJ26UOmD2EAe8ig-7tQk4KUBoMhsORrV7A424eq1XUKtBDBz%20eq%20WXcglccRjdoMqGtfc4y8yZJiejUxvQ9rhva-aecg7ydQ%208HACEN4MzCy36li5AZc-XXJUKC3Z89wPKURh5N4n2TcNL1PL9AmCc8Ux0T8pR-AJWGYIA)